# MySQL, filter duplicate sets

Tags: mysql, filter, set

I have a query that outputs combinations from a single table

```
Select  t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, t3.id as id3
    mytable t1, 
    mytable t2,
    mytable t3
WHERE condition = true
```

Which, when table contains 5 entries returns something as follows

```
row  id1, id2, id3

1.     1,  2,  3
2.     1,  2,  4
3.     1,  2,  5
4.     1,  3,  4
5.     1,  3,  5
6.     1,  3,  2
7.     2,  1,  3   
8.     2,  1,  4
9.     2,  1,  3
       etc....
```

I would like to filter out unique combinations of the 3, so in the example above,row 1,6 and 7 are the same set (they all contain 1, 2and 3), so only keep one of them.

Is there a way to produce another column that represents a unique value for that set?

For example is it possible to sort id1, id2 and id3 and produce a string that will be unique? (I know sorting works well on columns, but is it possible on rows in MySQL). Something like GROUP_CONCAT, but with the elements sorted.

Or is there another way to eliminate the duplicate sets?

Comment: give us your tale structure and sample data

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50460/order-by-and-then-concat

Comment: I am only returning id's from the table, so the rest of the table should be irrelevant. I will take a look at the suggestions on that page, though they will get ugly when the column count increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, inspired by a the other answers I realised the easiest is to add a condition where

```
SELECT t1.id as id1,
   t2.id as id2,
   t3.id as id3
FROM 
    mytable t1
    mytable t2
    mytable t3
WHERE    
    id1 > id2 AND id2 > id3
```

It should be fast, as there are no extra calculations before filtering, and will only allow one of the combinations of the set through.

Effectively we are filtering to only allow the sorted set through.

Comment: This way you could loose some right rows: 3 2 1 in case there are no 1 2 3, couldn't you? Or I miss something..

Comment: It doesn't work if you have the structure as I did in the fiddle. See it with your query, here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69bfc/8

Comment: Sorry I got sloppy cutting and pasting my answer (fixed now).

There is only one table and it is joined to itself. There should not be a problem of missing the 1,2,3 as the purpose of the query is to generate all combinations and then filter them.

Comment: @Jiri I am generating the whole table joined to itself, so I expect all sets to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

```
SELECT t1.id as id1,
   t2.id as id2,
   t3.id as id3
FROM t1, t2, t3
GROUP BY MD5(t1.id+" "+t2.id+" "+t3.id)
```

And I think the result is probably what you need, since
`md5(t1.id+" "+t2.id+" "+t3.id)` = `md5(t3.id+" "+t2.id+" "+t1.id)`
= `md5(t2.id+" "+t1.id+" "+t3.id)` etc..

**EDIT**:
I also added an inequality to avoid same id records,
as in `WHERE t1.id <> t2.id AND t2.id <> t3.id AND t1.id <> t3.id`.

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69bfc/3)

Comment: The md5 is redundant here and there are still collisions you have to deal with...

Comment: but say I have two rows,  containing ( 1, 50, 99) and ( 11, 49, 90), the totals are the same : 150, so the md5 will be the same. Yet the sets contain different entries

Comment: I actually tested it as a string. Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: @JiriFornous Could you give us an example of those collisions?

Comment: Ahh, does md5 work like that?
Actually, as the id's are number, I can just sort and eliminate by adding a clause id1 > id2 > id 3, as only the combination where that is true will produce one sorted set.

Answer (score 1):

It is overkilling, but you can get the clue:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  @t1:=LEAST(t1.id,t2.id,t3.id) AS id1,
  @t2:=GREATEST(t1.id,t2.id,t3.id) AS id2,
  t1.id+t2.id+t3.id-@t1-@t2 AS id3
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
```

Comment: I've used rather variables to gain effeciency

Comment: Could you please also explain it in words? I'm curious what is the logic behind it.

Comment: You mean my first comment or the answer?

Comment: I mean the answer. It returns the same result as mine, if you also add `WHERE t1.id <> t2.id AND t2.id <> t3.id AND t1.id <> t3.id`, but I get a hard time understanding the logic.

Comment: Sorry. I got it. You get the smallest id and the greatest id of each record and you subtract it from the sum, and `distinct` does the rest of it.